# Why when I try to send data to my Controller it returns me an error?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have a Model (User.js) and a Controller (UserController.js) and I set "ations: true" in the blueprints.js, I also have a function in UserController called "datos"

Using Postman I send a json object:

```
{
    "nombre": "Alexkin",
    "apellido": "Skywalker",
    "correo": "alexkin2@mail.com",
    "password": "123"
}
```

to this url: `localhost:1337/user/datos`

This is the code I have:

User.js

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        nombre:
        {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        apellido:
        {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        correo:
        {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
            unique: true,
            isEmail: true
        },
        password:
        {
            type: 'string'
        },
    },
};
```

UserController.js

```
module.exports = {
    datos: function (req,res)
    {
        usuario = req.allParams();
        User.findOrCreate(usuario)
        .exec(async(err, user, wasCreated)=> {
            if (err) { return res.serverError(err); }

            if(wasCreated) {
                sails.log('Created a new user: ' + user.nombre);
            }
            else {
                sails.log('Found existing user: ' + user.nombre);
            }
       });
    }
};
```

What I expect is to create an nonexistent user in my database but at the end I receive a message with this error:

> error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response:  UsageError: Invalid
>   initial data for new record. Details:   Missing value for required
>   attribute `nombre`.  Expected a string, but instead, got: undefined 
>   [?] See https://sailsjs.com/support for help...

Comment: What happens inside the findOrCreate method in the User module?

Comment: What is the value of `migrate` in `config/model.js` ?

Comment: I have 'safe' in models.js

Comment: Can you please `console.log(usuario)` before `User.findOrCreate()` and show us the value?

Comment: I did it already and it shows me the json object:

{ nombre: 'Alexkin',
  apellido: 'Skywalker',
  correo: 'alexkin4@mail.com',
  password: '123' }
error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response:
 UsageError: Invalid initial data for new record.
Details:
  Missing value for required attribute `nombre`.  Expected a string, but instead, got: undefined

Comment: To be honest, I think it's a configuration I'm skipping, but I don't know which one is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, the problem is that in versions < than 1.0, you have to send one object [Model.findOrCreate(data)], and in versions > than 1.0, you have to send two objects [Model.findOrCreate(find, data)]...

Answer (score 0):

Set the content-type in postman to application/json. And then paste the json in the "raw" tab.